# How to scroll to current index?

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I am making a file browser using QTreeView and QFileSystemModel.
It must be selected and scroll the tree to a selected item automatically. But it doesn't work scroll automatically without getting keyboard.

```
QString strFile = "/usr/bin/qmake";

QFileInfo fi(strFile);
QString dirFile = fi.dir().absolutePath();

QFileSystemModel model;
model.setRootPath("/");
model.setFilter(QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);

QTreeView view;
view.setModel(&model);
tree.setCurrentIndex(model.index(strFile));
tree.scrollTo(model.index(strFile));

view.show();
```

When executing above code, scroll is top but file is selected.

What's the problem not to scroll to selected item?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [scrollTo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#scrollTo)

```
view.scrollTo(view.currentIndex());
```

Optional pass the option where you want your item as a second parameter, like: `QAbstractItemView::PositionAtTop` or [other](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#ScrollHint-enum)

LE: i noticed that you actually call `scrollTo`, but you call it for some `tree` (that we can't see what it is) you should call that for `view`, same applies for `setCurrentIndex`.